# Are there math graduate schools without stressful tests?

Tags: graduate-school, exams, emotional-responses

I am one year from graduating and am starting to look for Graduate programs. I would like to know if there exist graduate programs where the focus is on research from the start (apparently this is the case in the UK).

I ask this because I have noticed I learn better when motivated by research than in regular courses. Additionally, because stressful long written exams frighten me and I would prefer to avoid them if it were a possibility. It would be nice at least to go somewhere where they are more flexible about exams, and place less value on them.

I ask this question, not seeking for a list of schools I might consider applying to, but to get a better idea of what graduate programs loook like. I would like to know if it’s worth it for me to focus on this, or if I should just look at the academics because focusing on this would be too restrictive. ( I cannot live by avoiding stress at all costs as mentioned in the comments).

Comment: What countries are you interested in?  In the US, most programs do have either a written or oral qualifying exam.  You should be able to find more info about the requirements of any given program on the department's web page, but I don't think it's on topic to ask for a list of all programs that don't have such exams.

Comment: While it's tempting to try and spend your life avoiding stress, learning how to effectively manage it is a much better idea. Have you considered talking to a counsellor or similar to try and improve your approach to stressful situations?

Comment: Voting to reopen, admittedly on a technicality (this is an existence question, not technically a shopping question), because I find it a very interesting question for the site.

Comment: I would just recommend reconsidering your choice. I definitely felt like this when I started my PhD. I held my nose and jumped in. Having the first two years to learn the fundamentals for an oral examination ended up ok, despite the stress I had about it. Learning to cope with that stress then will help when you have to deal with analogously stressful situations, like giving talks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In contrast to the exisiting answers, I am familiar with UK PhDs, so I will answer from that perspective.

In physics PhDs in the UK it is very unusual to have any exams at all during the PhD, and a quick check of Google shows that this holds true for pure maths as well; so the answer to your question is yes, such schools do exist.

Besides the comment I left about managing stress, I would therefore recommend looking into doing your PhD in the UK. The entry requirements may be higher than the USA (often a Master's degree is a pre-requisite, or at least a very good undergraduate degree) but you will avoid having to do any exams, as the research starts from day one.

Good luck.

Comment: The thesis defense counts as an exam though, doesn't it?

Comment: @Allure You mean the viva? Of course, but I don't think that's what the OP was describing. Can you name any PhDs that don't require a viva?

Comment: Hmm OP described exams as "long and timed", so yeah I agree the thesis defense doesn't count.

Comment: Very helpful answer.

Answer (score 7):

No one gets a PhD in mathematics (or any other subject) without experiencing stress, period. But there are different kinds of stress. Exam stress and research stress are different, and some people respond better to one or the other. In particular, the time constraints in research are obviously much much more flexible.

As Nate Eldredge notes in the comments, pretty much all US programs have some form of qualifying exam. UChicago is a notable exception, but their first-year graduate courses are more difficult, to make up for this. (We might formulate this principle as "conservation of stress.") But the important thing is that **even though students freak out over qualifying exams, these exams are merely a hoop to jump through, and are not the main focus of any PhD program.** Don't get me wrong, they are a *useful* hoop, but once they're over...they're over. You will stop stressing over exams, and start stressing over your thesis. Typically, qualifying exams happen around year 2 of a 5+ year program--the remaining years are all about research.

To put it another way, avoiding a good PhD program because of exams would be like avoiding a good vacation because of a fear of flying: perhaps necessary if you have a true, diagnosable phobia, but otherwise, you should grit your teeth and get through it.

Comment: Sorry, I am not very acquainted with the US system, what is the difference between the qualifying exam you mention most programs have and passing the nine first year courses at UChicago?

Comment: @Pitaya Qualifying exams take place outside of a particular course, and test a student's overall readiness to move on to the research phase of the program. They are written, oral, or both, depending on the school.

Answer (score 0):

My answer will be focused on the US.  (For other countries, the general idea might apply.  I just don't know enough about them.)

I can't tell from your question just how badly you fare with the stress of long, timed exams.  But it might be helpful to get evaluated by an educational psychologist.  The starting point for such an evaluation could be a visit to your primary care doctor.  Of course, few people find long, timed exams a walk in the park.  But students with a special health condition that makes exam stress truly impairing, often find that it can be made manageable with the help of academic adjustments.  The U.S. has a somewhat well defined way of documenting and applying for these adjustments, under Section 504 of the Rehabilitation Act.  Some possible accommodations might be: extra time, testing in an alternate location, a break every 40 minutes.  Sometimes people with an anxiety disorder find that just knowing they are allowed extra time eases a great deal of the anxiety (whether they use the extra time or not).

If you want more information about this: https://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/transition.html; or see what a particular university you're interested in has to say about "504 plan".  If you decide to apply for 504 eligibility, I recommend that you try to find an evaluator who will submit to insurance for at least partial reimbursement.

Now, separate from the above, I suggest that when you've gotten together a list of schools you're considering, you arrange for a "shadow" visit at each school on your short list.  That means that the department matches you up with a volunteer host student, and you go along to the host's normal classes with him or her, and have lunch together.  As you're getting to know the department, you'll want to find out what percentage of students pass their qualifying exams on the first try, and what percentage don't pass them at all.  Also, try to get a feel for how much hand holding the department provides in preparation for the quals.  There are schools that don't provide any, beyond office hours help for specific courses.  That might not be the ideal type of program for you.